# Reduce memory complexity in a bootstrap algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I wrote this function for bootstrapping.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np


def bootstrap(array):
    """
    :type array: np.ndarray
    :param array: a 1D NumPy array, where array[i] is the count of the
                  i-th item.
    :rtype: np.ndarray
    """
    size = int(array.sum())
    probabilities = array / size
    values = np.arange(arr.shape[0])
    bins = np.cumsum(probabilities)
    result = np.zeros(arr.shape[0])

    for val in values[np.digitize(np.random.random_sample(size), bins)]:
        result[val] += 1

    return result
```

I don't like the fact, that this line `values[np.digitize(np.random.random_sample(size), bins)]` creates the array of size `array.sum()`. I'd like to keep the memory complexity `O(n)`, where `n` is the `array`'s length. How can I make it lazier without significant speed sacrifices?

P.S.
In case you want to point me at the slow `for`-loop, I've Cythonised the real version to remove the slow Python loop.